# How can I find the shortest path between 100 moving targets? (Live demo included.)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graph-theory

### Background

This picture illustrates the problem:
[image: square_grid_with_arrows_giving_directions]

I can control the red circle.  The targets are the blue triangles.  The black arrows indicate the direction that the targets will move.

I want to collect all targets in the minimum number of steps.

Each turn I must move 1 step either left/right/up or down.

Each turn the targets will also move 1 step according to the directions shown on the board.

### Demo

I've put up a playable demo of the problem [here on Google appengine](http://penguinspuzzle.appspot.com/a_fishy_problem.html).

I would be very interested if anyone can beat the target score as this would show that my current algorithm is suboptimal.  (A congratulations message should be printed if you manage this!)

### Problem

My current algorithm scales really badly with the number of targets.  The time goes up exponentially and for 16 fish it is already several seconds.

I would like to compute the answer for board sizes of 32*32 and with 100 moving targets.

### Question

What is an efficient algorithm (ideally in Javascript) for computing the minimum number of steps to collect all targets?

### What I've tried

My current approach is based on memoisation but it is very slow and I don't know whether it will always generate the best solution.

I solve the subproblem of "what is the minimum number of steps to collect a given set of targets and end up at a particular target?".

The subproblem is solved recursively by examining each choice for the previous target to have visited.
I assume that it is always optimal to collect the previous subset of targets as quickly as possible and then move from the position you ended up to the current target as quickly as possible (although I don't know whether this is a valid assumption).

This results in n*2^n states to be computed which grows very rapidly.

The current code is shown below:

```
var DX=[1,0,-1,0];
var DY=[0,1,0,-1]; 

// Return the location of the given fish at time t
function getPt(fish,t) {
  var i;
  var x=pts[fish][0];
  var y=pts[fish][1];
  for(i=0;i<t;i++) {
    var b=board[x][y];
    x+=DX[b];
    y+=DY[b];
  }
  return [x,y];
}

// Return the number of steps to track down the given fish
// Work by iterating and selecting first time when Manhattan distance matches time
function fastest_route(peng,dest) {
  var myx=peng[0];
  var myy=peng[1];
  var x=dest[0];
  var y=dest[1];
  var t=0;
  while ((Math.abs(x-myx)+Math.abs(y-myy))!=t) {
    var b=board[x][y];
    x+=DX[b];
    y+=DY[b];
    t+=1;
  }
  return t;
}

// Try to compute the shortest path to reach each fish and a certain subset of the others
// key is current fish followed by N bits of bitmask
// value is shortest time
function computeTarget(start_x,start_y) {
  cache={};
  // Compute the shortest steps to have visited all fish in bitmask
  // and with the last visit being to the fish with index equal to last
  function go(bitmask,last) {
    var i;
    var best=100000000;
    var key=(last<<num_fish)+bitmask;
    if (key in cache) {
      return cache[key];
    }
    // Consider all previous positions
    bitmask -= 1<<last;
    if (bitmask==0) {
      best = fastest_route([start_x,start_y],pts[last]);
    } else {
      for(i=0;i<pts.length;i++) {
        var bit = 1<<i;
        if (bitmask&bit) {
          var s = go(bitmask,i);   // least cost if our previous fish was i
          s+=fastest_route(getPt(i,s),getPt(last,s));
          if (s<best) best=s;
        }
      }
    }
    cache[key]=best;
    return best;
  }
  var t = 100000000;
  for(var i=0;i<pts.length;i++) {
    t = Math.min(t,go((1<<pts.length)-1,i));
  }
  return t;
}
```

### What I've considered

Some options that I've wondered about are:

1. Caching of intermediate results.  The distance calculation repeats a lot of simulation and intermediate results could be cached.
   However, I don't think this would stop it having exponential complexity.
2. An A* search algorithm although it is not clear to me what an appropriate admissible heuristic would be and how effective this would be in practice.
3. Investigating good algorithms for the travelling salesman problem and see if they apply to this problem.
4. Trying to prove that the problem is NP-hard and hence unreasonable to be seeking an optimal answer for it.

Comment: I would go for #4 and subsequently #3: With large enough boards, it mimics the TSP quite well.

Comment: Is TSP known to be NP-hard on a square grid?

Comment: As far as I know, TSP is NP-hard with the euclidean metric as well as the manhattan metric (square grid).

Comment: Euclidean TSP, indeed, is NP-C. I assume the same for Manhattan TSP.

Comment: If you do it by simple tree-search, yes, it will be exponential. However, if you can find a decent heuristic at each step, it may not be truly optimal, but it might be very good. One possible heuristic would be, looking at the current set of fish, which one could be reached most quickly? A secondary heuristic could be, which 2 fish could I reach most quickly?

Comment: @MikeDunlavey that would correspond to the greedy TSP algorithm, and it works very well in practice. Going for the closest fish seems like a good idea

Comment: Looking in the neighourhood for closest fish sounds very sensible.  Would it make sense to try to use this greedy approach to generate an admissible heuristic for an A* search - or does the fact that it may be NP-hard mean that 100 targets is beyond the reach of such a search?

Comment: 2^100 is too much to search through. Even 2^50 is quite large. You won't get that low.

Comment: If you use a greedy heuristic, you should be able to have any number of targets.

Comment: Interesting; is there a way, perhaps, to use a greedy algorithm to also get a lower bound on the number of steps?  (It clearly gives an upper bound by demonstrating a particular route, but if an optimal answer is impossible then I would like to be able to establish a range of possible values for the optimum route)

Comment: One possibility might be to use a minimum spanning tree as an estimate for the remaining length.  I could do this for stationary targets but I'm not sure how to generate such a minimum spanning tree when the targets are moving?

Comment: Have you searched the literature? I found these papers which seems to analyse your problem: - "Tracking moving targets and the non- stationary traveling salesman problem": http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.85.9940 - "The moving-target traveling salesman problem": http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.57.6403 **UPDATE 1:** The above two papers seems to concentrate on linear movement for the euclidian metric.

Comment: Heuristics are what you use when formal concerns aren't good enough. Just bang it out and see what you get.

Comment: 16 fish currently takes 12.5 seconds on a Nexus 4 phone.

Comment: +1 for one of the best questions I've seen lately, both for content and structure.

Comment: Do you *have to* move the red circle on every turn?  If so, then it's possible for there to be fish that you can never catch, because the only times when you can place the red circle at a particular (x, y) location will be be either even-numbered times or odd-numbered times, depending on the Manhattan distance between (x, y) and the circle's start position.  A fish that visits (x, y) will likewise only visit at either even-numbered or odd-numbered times. For the circle to be able to catch the fish at (x, y), they must both be able to visit it at the same subset of times.

Comment: You are quite right.  You do have to move every turn and this has a parity problem.  In the case I am interested in (and in the demo code) I always have the targets on squares of the same parity.

Comment: "collect the previous subset of targets as quickly as possible and then move from the position you ended up to the current target as quickly as possible" -- this is fine.  You'll never gain an advantage by delaying a capture.  After all, you can always capture a target 'early', then follow the path it would have taken (which is equivalent to delaying a capture).

Comment: re Pruning: Say you want to know which target to capture next.  For each target, find the soonest meeting place.  If a shortest path to a particular meeting place 'A' walks over meeting place 'B', you don't need to consider capturing 'A' next.  You're never better off skipping a free capture.
Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to apply this to your search, since you're searching 'backwards'.

Comment: I just ate all the fish on your demo in 18 steps (it predicted 19), but I didn't keep track of what I was doing and it didn't congratulate me. Hopefully your app logged the run if it's of any interest.

Comment: I'm afraid all the work is done client side so I don't log anything.  If you manage this again, then please take a screenshot.  I would be very interested to see it!  Note that the level is automatically reset to the start of the same level after you collect all the targets so you can try the same level as many times as you wish.

Answer (score 13):

### Greedy method

One approach suggested in the comments is to go to the closest target first.

I've put up a version of the demo which includes the cost calculated via this greedy method [here](http://penguinspuzzle.appspot.com/a_fishy_problem3.html).

The code is:

```
function greedyMethod(start_x,start_y) {
  var still_to_visit = (1<<pts.length)-1;
  var pt=[start_x,start_y];
  var s=0;
  while (still_to_visit) {
    var besti=-1;
    var bestc=0;
    for(i=0;i<pts.length;i++) {
      var bit = 1<<i;
      if (still_to_visit&bit) {
        c = fastest_route(pt,getPt(i,s));
        if (besti<0 || c<bestc) {
          besti = i;
          bestc = c;
        }
      }
    }
    s+=c;
    still_to_visit -= 1<<besti;
    pt=getPt(besti,s);
  }
  return s;
}
```

For 10 targets it is around twice the optimal distance, but sometimes much more (e.g. *4) and occasionally even hits the optimum.

This approach is very efficient so I can afford some cycles to improve the answer.

Next I'm considering using ant colony methods to see if they can explore the solution space effectively.

### Ant colony method

An [Ant colony method](http://www.idsia.ch/~luca/acs-bio97.pdf) seems to work remarkable well for this problem.  The link in this answer now compares the results when using both greedy and ant colony method.

The idea is that ants choose their route probabilistically based on the current level of pheromone.  After every 10 trials, we deposit additional pheromone along the shortest trail they found.

```
function antMethod(start_x,start_y) {
  // First establish a baseline based on greedy
  var L = greedyMethod(start_x,start_y);
  var n = pts.length;
  var m = 10; // number of ants
  var numrepeats = 100;
  var alpha = 0.1;
  var q = 0.9;
  var t0 = 1/(n*L);

  pheromone=new Array(n+1); // entry n used for starting position
  for(i=0;i<=n;i++) {
    pheromone[i] = new Array(n);
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
      pheromone[i][j] = t0; 
  }

  h = new Array(n);
  overallBest=10000000;
  for(repeat=0;repeat<numrepeats;repeat++) {
    for(ant=0;ant<m;ant++) {
      route = new Array(n);
      var still_to_visit = (1<<n)-1;
      var pt=[start_x,start_y];
      var s=0;
      var last=n;
      var step=0;
      while (still_to_visit) {
        var besti=-1;
        var bestc=0;
        var totalh=0;
        for(i=0;i<pts.length;i++) {
          var bit = 1<<i;
          if (still_to_visit&bit) {
            c = pheromone[last][i]/(1+fastest_route(pt,getPt(i,s)));
            h[i] = c;
            totalh += h[i];
            if (besti<0 || c>bestc) {
              besti = i;
              bestc = c;
            }
          }
        }
        if (Math.random()>0.9) {
          thresh = totalh*Math.random();
          for(i=0;i<pts.length;i++) {
            var bit = 1<<i;
            if (still_to_visit&bit) {
              thresh -= h[i];
              if (thresh<0) {
                besti=i;
                break;
              }
            }
          }
        }
        s += fastest_route(pt,getPt(besti,s));
        still_to_visit -= 1<<besti;
        pt=getPt(besti,s);
        route[step]=besti;
        step++;
        pheromone[last][besti] = (1-alpha) * pheromone[last][besti] + alpha*t0;
        last = besti;
      }
      if (ant==0 || s<bestantscore) {
        bestroute=route;
        bestantscore = s;
      }
    }
    last = n;
    var d = 1/(1+bestantscore);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
      var besti = bestroute[i];
      pheromone[last][besti] = (1-alpha) * pheromone[last][besti] + alpha*d;
      last = besti;
    }
    overallBest = Math.min(overallBest,bestantscore);
  }
  return overallBest;
}
```

### Results

This ant colony method using 100 repeats of 10 ants is still very fast (37ms for 16 targets compared to 3700ms for the exhaustive search) and seems very accurate.

The table below shows the results for 10 trials using 16 targets:

```
   Greedy   Ant     Optimal
   46       29      29
   91       38      37
  103       30      30
   86       29      29
   75       26      22
  182       38      36
  120       31      28
  106       38      30
   93       30      30
  129       39      38
```

The ant method seems significantly better than greedy and often very close to optimal.

Comment: Nice. 


You might not have optimal results from the exhaustive search just yet (or possibly never due to its intractability!) but it'd be interesting to see how ant colony scales with board size (32x32) with the same number of targets.

Answer (score 8):

The problem may be represented in terms of the Generalized Traveling Salesman Problem, and then converted to a conventional Traveling Salesman Problem. This is a well-studied problem. It is possible that the most efficient solutions to the OP's problem are no more efficient than solutions to the TSP, but by no means certain (I am probably failing to take advantage of some aspects of the OP's problem structure that would allow for a quicker solution, such as its cyclical nature). Either way, it is a good starting point.

From [C. Noon & J.Bean, *An Efficient Transformation of the Generalized Traveling Salesman Problem*](http://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/6834/ban3102.0001.001.pdf;jsessionid=FE47BED6BEFA1D7A88661CBCABEF64AC?sequence=5):

> The *Generalized Traveling Salesman Problem* (GTSP) is a useful model for problems involving decisions of selection and sequence. The asymmetric version of the problem is defined on a directed graph with nodes N, connecting arcs A and a vector of corresponding arc costs c. The nodes are pregrouped into m mutually exclusive and exhaustive nodesets. Connecting arcs are defined only between nodes belonging to different sets, that is, there are no intraset arcs. Each defined arc has a corresponding non-negative cost. The GTSP can be stated as *the problem of finding a minimum cost m-arc cycle which includes exactly one node from each nodeset*.

For the OP's problem:

- Each member of `N` is a particular fish's location at a particular time. Represent this as `(x, y, t)`, where `(x, y)` is a grid coordinate, and `t` is the time at which the fish will be at this coordinate. For the leftmost fish in the OP's example, the first few of these (1-based) are: `(3, 9, 1), (4, 9, 2), (5, 9, 3)` as the fish moves right.
- For any member of N let `fish(n_i)` return the ID of the fish represented by the node. For any two members of N we can calculate `manhattan(n_i, n_j)` for the manhattan distance between the two nodes, and `time(n_i, n_j`) for the time offset between the nodes.
- The number of disjoint subsets m is equal to the number of fish. The disjoint subset `S_i` will consist only of the nodes for which `fish(n) == i`.
- If for two nodes `i` and `j` `fish(n_i) != fish(n_j)` then there is an arc between `i` and `j`.
- The cost between node i and node j is `time(n_i, n_j)`, or undefined if `time(n_i, n_j) < distance(n_i, n_j)` (i.e. the location can't be reached before the fish gets there, perhaps because it is backwards in time). Arcs of this latter type can be removed.
- An extra node will need to be added representing the location of the player with arcs and costs to all other nodes.

Solving this problem would then result in a single visit to each node subset (i.e. each fish is obtained once) for a path with minimal cost (i.e. minimal time for all fish to be obtained).

The paper goes on to describe how the above formulation may be transformed into a traditional Traveling Salesman Problem and subsequently solved or approximated with existing techniques. I have not read through the details but another paper that does this in a way it proclaims to be efficient is [this one](http://www.ee.ucla.edu/~abehzad/ICSE02.pdf).

There are obvious issues with complexity. In particular, the node space is infinite! This can be alleviated by only generating nodes up to a certain time horizon. If `t` is the number of timesteps to generate nodes for and `f` is the number of fish then the size of the node space will be `t * f`. A node at time `j` will have at most `(f - 1) * (t - j)` outgoing arcs (as it can't move back in time or to its own subset). The total number of arcs will be in the order of `t^2 * f^2` arcs. The arc structure can probably be tidied up, to take advantage of the fact the fish paths are eventually cyclical. The fish will repeat their configuration once every lowest common denominator of their cycle lengths so perhaps this fact can be used.

I don't know enough about the TSP to say whether this is feasible or not, and I don't think it means that the problem posted is *necessarily* NP-hard... but it is one approach towards finding an optimal or bounded solution.

Comment: Thanks, this is new to me and very interesting.  I think I should be able to use this transformation in combination with the Christofides algorithm to efficiently find a solution within an approximation factor of 3/2 of the optimal.  If I get it to work I'll add the produced routes to the demo page.

Comment: Ah, I think there is a problem with my plan in that although my original problem is a complete graph satisfying an appropriate inequality on the metric, the transformation described results in a incomplete graph and so the Christofides algorithm no longer applies.  Thanks anyway for the interesting perspective.

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention that triangle inequality no longer holds. It's a good jumping off point for heuristic solutions and more general approximations however.

Answer (score 1):

I think another approch would be:

- calculate the path of the targets - predictive.
- than use [Voronoi diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram)

Quote wikipedia:

*In mathematics, a Voronoi diagram is a way of dividing space into a number of regions. A set of points (called seeds, sites, or generators) is specified beforehand and for each seed there will be a corresponding region consisting of all points closer to that seed than to any other.*

So, you choose a target, follow it's path for some steps and set a seed point there. Do this with all other targets as well and you get a voroni diagram. Depending in which area you are, you move to the seedpoint of it. Viola, you got the first fish. Now repeat this step until you cought them all.